# Knockout with Monaco - Close Modal Not Updating

Tags: knockout.js, monaco-editor

I have a page that has a monaco editor textbox. I have an Edit button that, on clicked, opens a modal window with a new monaco textbox (it gets initialized with the value from the model bound to first textbox).

The goal is to edit the value while in the modal and click OK which will update the value on the main page. What I am finding is that the model on the main page is updated correctly but this is not reflected in the monaco editor that is bound to that value.

How do I make the monaco editor that is bound to the initial textbox show the updated value when the modal is closed?

Tagging monaco and knockout but I think this is more a monaco editor since the knockout part seems to work. If I add an additional textbox and bind to the value, I can see it gets the new value when the modal closes but what is shown in the monaco box is not updated.

Here are some parts of the code (I am not able to include everything).

```
let ActivityExpressionViewModel = function (data) {
let self = this;

if (data != null) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
} else {
    self.expression = ko.observable("");
}

self.Initialize = function (expression) {
    this.expression(expression);
}

self.EditExpression = function (data, event) {
    showModal({
        viewModel: new EditExpressionViewModel(self.expression),
        context: this
    })
    .done(function (result) {
        self.UpdateExpression(result);
    });
}

self.UpdateExpression = function (newExpression) {
    if (newExpression != "") {
        self.expression(newExpression);
    }
}
};

let EditExpressionViewModel = function (currentExpressionAccessor) {
let self = this;
self.currentExpressionAccessor = currentExpressionAccessor;
self.expression = ko.observable(currentExpressionAccessor());

self.template = "editExpressionModalTemplate";

self.CompleteEditing = function () {
    this.modal.close(this.expression());
}

self.CancelEditing = function () {
    this.modal.close();
}
}

let monacoEditor = null;
let currentViewModel = null;

ko.bindingHandlers.activityExpressionMonacoEditor = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
    currentViewModel = allBindingsAccessor().currentViewModel;

    monacoEditor = monaco.editor.create(element,
        {
            codeLens: false,
            language: 'c#',
        });

    monacoEditor.setValue(currentViewModel.expression());

    monacoEditor.getModel().onDidChangeContent(event => {
        let value = monacoEditor.getValue();
        currentViewModel.expression(value);
    });

    monacoEditor.onDidBlurEditorText((event) => {
        if (currentViewModel != null) {
            currentViewModel.ValidateExpression();
        }
    });
}
};
```

Ideas? FYI - NOT a Javascript/Knockout expert.

Comment: Modal close fires the onDidBlurEditorText event?

Comment: @Martlark, it is being fired when I move focus from the boxes after directly editing them (which means if I click the "Ok" on the modal, it fires but on that current monaco instance. The instance of the parent is not fired again. I think that is what I am missing - to force the monaco control on the main window to refresh after the observable it is bound to has changed (which I thought would happen normally).

Comment: I have discovered that it's not the correct editor being updated. When I open the modal, I create a new editor (it has id 2). When the modal closes and the event on the parent viewmodel is fired, the current editor is still ID 2 instead of 1. I am creating the editors in global scope and apparently trampling over them. Looking at how to create the editor (from a knockout binding) but in the scope of the view model itself.

Comment: This JavaScript and knockoutjs of yours appears very advanced.  I'm sure you'll manage.